# How can I change the color of the Eclipse neon.3 menu bar on Windows 10?

Tags: java, android, css, windows, eclipse

As you can see here my Eclipse is looking pretty snazzy here with the Darkest Dark theme.  My question here is how can I apply similar color to the Menu bar?  The title bar is taken care of with my grey Windows 10 theme, but the white menu bar is just so distracting.

[My Dark Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEih1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible. It is the standard way for it to look with this theme, if not all themes.